# service fabric - reliable services life cycle - can listeners be called before run async function

Tags: azure-service-fabric

According to official documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reliable-services-lifecycle

"

1. The service is constructed.
2. Then, in parallel, two things happen:
   StatelessService.CreateServiceInstanceListeners() is invoked and any returned listeners are opened. ICommunicationListener.OpenAsync() is called on each listener.
   The service's StatelessService.RunAsync() method is called.
3. If present, the service's StatelessService.OnOpenAsync() method is called. This call is an uncommon override, but it is available. Extended service initialization tasks can be started at this time.
   "

So if CreateServiceInstanceListeners can be invoked before RunAsync, does it also mean an external service can invoke the API of the service before it's RunAsync has been called?
Or since the third step is OnOpenAsync we are guaranteed that our service API methods will be triggered after the third step is complete (meaning the RunAsync has already started) ?

Answer (score 1):

- So if CreateServiceInstanceListeners can be invoked before RunAsync, does it also mean an external service can invoke the API of the service before it's RunAsync has been called?

Yes, as soon as communication listeners are opened, calls can be made to them.
The Internal OnOpenAsync is for internal components.

RunAsync won't be called on secondary replicas, but they can create listeners.

Comment: Thanks LoekD, have you found some documentation to support it?
I couldn't find information about this